# LyX | synchronize settings

Tags: lyx, files

Is it possible to somehow synchronize various LyX settings (i.e files of settings) of whatever I'd want (style, macros, UI, key bindings, document classes, etc.), maybe even through some 3rd-party service (like cloud storage services, in the worst scenario)?

I have 2 computers with LyX installed on them (with the same operating system), and I want to keep document classes, styles, UI style, macros, keyboard shortcuts and others synced between the 2 installations.

I assume that it's possible to find the relevant LyX files that refer to the location of the desired files, and change the references to (a) local cloud-syncing folder(s) (I know that OneDrive, GoogleDrive & Dropbox have desktop clients that can sync local files to the cloud via dedicated and/or selected folders).
 Then, if the desired files are stored in such folders, they'd sync from/to the cloud, and since they'll be stored locally, LyX wouldn't have a problem using them (and it won't be slow, since it wouldn't download anything).

That would require starting to find the relevant files in which there the paths to the desired files are defined, and changing the files.

Has anyone ever done such synchronization (not necessarily via Google Drive, DropBox or OneDrive) sucessfuly? I'm not sure if I'd be able to do it successful, and it might screw my LyX installation up, and I've no time to experiment.

Comment: I'm guessing a lot of this is in the User directory: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/UserDir Which document classes are installed is not entirely up to LyX though, those are a part of the TeX distribution you have installed (typically TeX Live, MacTeX or MikTeX).

Comment: The thing you said about the document classes - I know, and it's less important to me (specifically, I'm looking to sync custom ones created in LyX at least for now). And I have manually edited files of LyX, so where they are and where their paths are defined is not what I'm caring to know about, mostly. I'll take a look at your link, though.

Comment: The link just gives you information about how to find the user directory, and finding that would be a logical first step, but if you already knew where it was, then that info isn't needed. I've never done anything like that, so beyond the naive suggestion to  move the user dir to e.g. Dropbox, and symlink to that, I can't help.